# Suggestion on more efficient way for a specific code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently learning from "LPTHW - Zed Shaw" and "Automating the boring stuff".

There is a nested directory of the type {'string1': {inner dict 1}, 'string2':{inner dict 2},...}.

I want a non nested consolidated directory of all the keys and values from all of the {inner dicts}. I have written below code, but I am not convinced it is the most efficient way. I am wanting suggestions on if the code can be simplified by:

1. Utilising logic within single loop by making use of some other modules and methods
2. How that new method is efficient from processing point of view

```py
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}

item_list = []
count_list = []
consolidated = {}
all_items_list = list(allGuests.values()) #This is a list of sub dictionaries

#Loop for the number of guests who brought items
for guest in range(0, len(allGuests)):

#Creating 2 separate lists for 'items' and 'their count'

    item_list = item_list + list(all_items_list[guest].keys())
    count_list = count_list + list(all_items_list[guest].values())

#Creating a consolidated dictionary
for index in range(0, len(item_list)):

    if not consolidated.get(item_list[index]):
    consolidated.setdefault(item_list[index], count_list[index])

    else:
    consolidated[item_list[index]] = consolidated[item_list[index]] + count_list[index]

pprint.pprint(consolidated)
```

```
{'apple pies': 1, 'apples': 7, 'cups': 3, 'ham sandwiches': 3, 'pretzels': 12}
```

Comment: If you have code that works and you're just asking for peer review to improve it, your question should be asked at [codereview.se] instead. It's exactly the reason that site was created. This site is for questions about non-working code issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reasonable simplified method for your consideration :)

```py
consolidated = []
for guest in allGuests.values():
    for key, value in guest.items():
        consolidated.append((key, value))
consolidated = dict(consolidated)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks will_f.

Below code worked:-

 consolidated = {}
 for guest in allGuests.values():
     for key, value in guest.items():
         if not consolidated.get(key):
             consolidated.setdefault(key, value)

         else:
             consolidated[key] = consolidated[key] + value

         pprint.pprint(consolidated)
```